# Пунктуация при уточнении

Tags: пунктуация

«В первые же часы жизни новорожденный начинает обучаться (подражать) и на основе визуальных, не связанных с непосредственным жизнеобеспечением впечатлений» После «жизнеобеспечением» нужна запятая?

Answer (score 1):

Да, запятая нужна, так как иначе появляется бессмысленное словосочетание *жизнеобеспечение впечатлений*.

Comment: Спасибо! я второй день на этом сервисе и не поняла, как благодарить. Нажимаю на стрелочки - ничего не меняется. В комментариях, пишут, "избегайте говорить спасибо"))

Comment: В комментариях "спасибо" можно, если комментарий этим не ограничивается. В ответах - да, там это не к месту.

Answer (score 0):

Я предполагаю, что после "впечатлений" идет точка, иначе синтаксис фразы весьма неоднозначен.
В этом случае по грамматике запятая опциональна. Но не совсем. Она от смысла зависит. Если "визуальных" и "не связанных с непосредственным жизнеобеспечением" рассматриваются как однородные определения, то запятая не нужна. Если же второе (не связанных) раскрывает или уточняет первое (визуальных), то необходима. Я далек от подобной тематики и решить за автора не могу, что здесь имеет место. По мне так и то и другое - тарабарщина, "визуальный" и "жизнеобеспечение" - это вещи с разных планет, как они в одной связке тут оказались, совсем не понятно. Поэтому из двух зол готов выбрать меньшее и запятую эту поставить, пусть читатель, профессионал, голову ломает, что автор хотел сказать. Да и соображения Марка Иза готов принять к учету. Действительно без запятой возникает нежелательная зрительная состыковка двух нестыкуемых ни по грамматике, ни по смыслу существительных.

***В первые же часы жизни новорожденный начинает обучаться (подражать) [и] на основе визуальных, не связанных с непосредственным жизнеобеспечением,  впечатлений.***

Тут другое. Мне категорически не нравится усилительная частица "и". надо контекст смотреть, зачем она тут. Где-то раньше говорилось, что новорожденный (или кто еще) начинает подражать на какой-то другой основе? Мне тркдно представить такое по структуре фразы. Если нет, о таком ранее не говорится, то удаляете это "И" не задумываясь.